# Creating a Zigzag Structure in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was working on few structure for the 3D tool that I am developing for which I was wanting a zigzag structure like this https://jsfiddle.net/cdu96z3c/21/ . As of now i have achieved it by iterating the same function which produce 'V' multiple times to achive it, I would like to achieve the same using one single geometry and mesh.

```
function modelShape(points){
   this.shape = new THREE.Shape();
   this.shape.moveTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
   for(var i=1; i<points.length; i++){
       this.shape.lineTo(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
   }
   this.shape.lineTo(points[0][0], points[0][1]);
}
function structure(i){
   points = [
      [-1.5,0],
      [-1.5,.5],
      [0,3.5],
      [1.5,.5],
      [1.5,0],
      [0,3]
   ];
   modelShape.call(this, points);
   var extrudeSettings = { amount: .25, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 0, steps: 1, bevelSize: 0, bevelThickness: 0 };
   var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( this.shape, extrudeSettings );
   geometry.dynamic = true;
   geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
   var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ 
           color: 0xafafaf,
           metalness: 0.9
   });
   this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
   this.mesh.position.set(i*3,0,0)
}
for(i = 0;i < 20; i++){
    var struc = new structure(i);
    scene.add(struc.mesh);
}
```

Comment: You can repeat the data in `points` via a loop with some shift on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small function that generates points acoording to some parameters to form a zigzag shape:

```js
// amount - number of zigzag segments
// width - width of one segment
// height - height of one segment
// thickness - thickness/width of the line
function generateZigZagPoints(amount, width, height, thickness) {

  let points = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    points.push([ i * width, 0 ]);
    points.push([ i * width + width / 2, height ]);
  }

  points.push([ amount * width, 0 ]);
  points.push([ amount * width, -thickness ]);

  for (let i = amount; i > -1; i--) {
    points.push([ i * width + width / 2, height - thickness ]);
    points.push([ i * width, -thickness ]);
  }

  return points;

}
```